# How to fix Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')

Tags: node.js, node.js-fs

new at NodeJS and I'm making a hands-on course, but I'm kind of stuck atm, help appreciated:

File: app.js
Content:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function readAndwrite() {
  var readableStream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');
  var writeableStream = fs.createWriteStream('duplicate.txt');
  readableStream.pipe(writeableStream);
  console.log("Content copied to duplciate.txt");
}

module.exports.readAndWrite = readAndWrite
```

Current error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')

Comment: The error is most likely not coming from the code you've posted here. [`fs.createReadStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscreatereadstreampath-options) does not return null streams

Comment: if input.txt is in the same folder as app.js, then am referencing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There are few reasons why you are getting this error, but let me point the first and the most likely cause. You need to check the file you are trying to access if it exists. So I have refactor the code like so:

```
function readAndWrite() {
 try {
    const sourceFile = "input.txt";
    const destinationFile = "duplicate.txt";
    if (sourceFile && fs.existsSync(sourceFile)) {
      var readableStream = fs.createReadStream(sourceFile);
      var writeableStream = fs.createWriteStream(destinationFile);
      readableStream.pipe(writeableStream);
      console.log("Content copied to duplciate.txt");
    } else {
      console.log("File not exist");
    }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
   }
}
```